# EF Core nullable one-to-one relation does not allow duplicate nulls

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, .net-core

In EF Core I have two models that have a 1-1 relation between each other.

MultiPlayerPlay:

```
public class MultiPlayerPlay
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    ...

    // Relations
    ...
    public long? CallerPlayerPlayId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserMutantPlay CallerPlayerPlay { get; set; }
    public long? CalledPlayerPlayId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserMutantPlay CalledPlayerPlay { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and UserMutantPlay:

```
public class UserMutantPlay
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    ...

    // Relations
    ...
    public long? MultiPlayerPlayAsCallerId { get; set; }
    public virtual MultiPlayerPlay MultiPlayerPlayAsCaller { get; set; }
    public long? MultiPlayerPlayAsCalledId { get; set; }
    public virtual MultiPlayerPlay MultiPlayerPlayAsCalled { get; set; }
}
```

and the relations:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<MultiPlayerPlay>()
            .HasOne(mpp => mpp.CallerPlayerPlay)
            .WithOne(p => p.MultiPlayerPlayAsCaller)
            .HasForeignKey<MultiPlayerPlay>(mpp => mpp.CallerPlayerPlayId)
            //.HasForeignKey<UserMutantPlay>(ump => ump.MultiPlayerPlayAsCallerId)
            .IsRequired(false)
            .OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<MultiPlayerPlay>()
            .HasOne(mpp => mpp.CalledPlayerPlay)
            .WithOne(p => p.MultiPlayerPlayAsCalled)
            .HasForeignKey<MultiPlayerPlay>(mpp => mpp.CalledPlayerPlayId)
            //.HasForeignKey<UserMutantPlay>(ump => ump.MultiPlayerPlayAsCalledId)
            .IsRequired(false)
            .OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

As you see MultiPlayerPlay has two 1-1 relations to UserMutantPlay. But when I try to run this statement:

```
    MultiPlayerPlay multiPlayerPlay = new MultiPlayerPlay()
        {
            CallerPlayerId = inviterUser.Id,
            CalledPlayerId = invitedUser.Id,
            StillRunning = true,
            StillRunningForCaller = true,
            StillRunningForCalled = true,
            MutantId = GetRandomMutantIdByLevelId(dbContext, inviterUser.Id, invitedUser.Id),
        };

        dbContext.MultiPlayerPlays.Add(multiPlayerPlay);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

First time it worked fine. The next times, it mentions that I can't have multiple null values in the FK relation. The error is this:

{System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.MultiPlayerPlays' with unique index 'IX_MultiPlayerPlays_CalledPlayerPlayId'. The duplicate key value is ().
The statement has been terminated.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, String executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues, Boolean closeConnection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
ClientConnectionId:7c7adc7b-0172-4134-89c9-6b5f050ac860
Error Number:2601,State:1,Class:14}